# Turing Machine support

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines

I have a language:

(XF*X|F)*

over the alphabet:

{X,F}

How can I get/design a Turing machine to recognize that language?
Any guidance or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: @Rhymoid: This doesn't look like a graduate-level research question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's trivial:

[image]

```
digraph _ {
    _ [ shape=none, label="" ]
    1 [ shape=doublecircle ]
    2 [ shape=circle ]
    _ -> 1
    1 -> 1 [ label="F" ]
    1 -> 2 [ label="X" ]
    2 -> 2 [ label="F" ]
    2 -> 1 [ label="X" ]
}
```

Comment: That's a DFA, not a TM. A TM also has annotations for tape direction.

Comment: @Rhymoid, yeah, also it always writes a character while it moves (possibly the same it just read). But I guess OP will manage to add arrows to the graph …

Comment: I'm struggling a little to add in the labels. Is there a good starting point or something that would help me.

Comment: The conventions differ. I know the convention "read, write, direction". E.g. the labels would read "F,F,->" or "X,X,->".